# PHP - XML Parsing (Trying to get property of non-object)

Tags: php, xml

Good morning!

I try to describe my problem: I have a language class and in the class there is a function `Text(category, item)`.
so I can call the function like:

```
Language::Text("indexPage", "hello_world");
```

And the output would be:

```
Hello World!
```

The Values of the items are in a xml file.

Structure of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<languageBase>
    <language filename="en" language="English">
        <category name="indexPage">
            <item name="hello_world"><![CDATA[Hello World!]]></item>
        </category>
    </language>
</languageBase>
```

But if I use the function `Text(..)`, I get an error:

> Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Mvc\system\classes\class.language.php on line 20

This is my class:

```
<?php
    if (!defined("OK")) {
        header("Location: ../");
    }

    class Language {
        private static $_language = "de";

        public static function params($string) {
            $string = str_replace("%USERNAME%", User::GetUsername(User::$_id, 1), $string);
            $string = str_replace("%@USERNAME%", User::GetUsername(User::$_id), $string);
            return $string;
        }

        public static function Text($category, $item) {
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents(self::GetPath()));
            $category = "indexPage";
            $item = "hello_world";
            $obj = $xml->xpath("/languageBase/language/category[@name=\"{$category}\"]/item[@name=\"{$item}\"]");
            return $obj->entry;
        }

        public static function Set($language) {
            $_SESSION[SESSION_LANGUAGE] = $language;
        }

        public static function Get() {
            if(isset($_SESSION[SESSION_LANGUAGE])) {
                if(file_exists("system/lang/".$_SESSION[SESSION_LANGUAGE].".xml")) {
                    self::$_language = $_SESSION[SESSION_LANGUAGE];
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION[SESSION_LANGUAGE] = self::$_language;
            }

            return self::$_language;
        }

        public static function GetPath() {
            return "system/lang/".self::Get().".xml";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$xml->category['indexPage']` doesn't exist. It's not indexed by the `name` attribute.

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: you can access attributes via brackets, like `$xml->category['name']`. I'm afraid, you have to loop through you categories and find the correct one, identifier by your name attribute.

Comment: thanks joshua. i've edited my post. i've tryed with xpath but its the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never define that you want to access the attribute called "name". There could be any number of other attributes like "id".

What you could do is use xpath like this:

```
public static function Text($category, $item) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents(self::GetPath()));
    $items = $xml->xpath("//category[@name='$category']/item[@name='$item']");
    if ($items[0]) {
        return (string)$items[0];
    }
    return null;
}
```

With this solution it is important to make sure that $category and $item never contains xpath control characters, i.e. $item = 'my[item]' would produce errors.
In that case, you would have to escape $item and $category somehow.

xpath is not always very straight forward to understand. A nice resource is: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Xpath 1.0 allows no escaping for string literals. You can use `'value'`, `"value"` or `concat('value1', "value2")`, depending on the kind of quotes your value has.